# How can I undo "Don’t recommend channel" feedback I provided by mistake?

Tags: youtube

I accidentally provided "Don’t recommend channel" feedback to YouTube for a channel I actually like.

How can I undo this so YouTube recommends this channel?

Comment: @galacticninja you are correct.  I selected [recommendations] not realizing it was an alias for [webapp-rec].

Answer (score 3):

I am not aware of any way to delete the “Don’t recommend channel” feedback for just a single channel.

You can, however, delete **all** the “Not interested” and “Don’t recommend channel” feedback you've previously provided.

**From YouTube Help:**

> ##### [Clear “Not interested” and “Don’t recommend channel” feedback](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/6342839?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop#:%7E:text=Clear%20%E2%80%9CNot%20interested%E2%80%9D%20and%20%E2%80%9CDon%E2%80%99t%20recommend%20channel%E2%80%9D%20feedback)
>
> Your “Not Interested” and “Don’t recommend channel” feedback may be used to tune your recommendations. To clear all the “Not interested” and “Don’t recommend channel” feedback you've submitted:
>
> 1. Go to [My Activity](https://myactivity.google.com/). You might need to sign in to your Google Account.
> 2. Find **Other Google activity** in the left-hand Menu or under the My Activity banner.
> 3. Select "YouTube 'Not interested' feedback," then select **Delete**.
>
> View our other articles for more info about [watch history, search history](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/57711), and improving your recommendations.

[image]

Comment: Great answer Franck. I made some edits to merge the two parts of your answer together for clarity. Q: can I do  "x"  A: No but you can do "y"  flagging with *temporary* comment in case you don't approve. Flag comment as "no longer needed" once you've seen it.